Break a cipher crypted by substitution
I'm new to crptography and I'm kinda stucked with one question here:

A given text M, is tokenized in characters and bi-characters (e.g. 'a', 'as', etc.), space and special character included
Every token is randomly assigned to an 8-bit binary number (different each time for sure), so the size of the dictionary is at most 256
Given cipher and python code for the encryption

So I tried to break with frequency attack:

Find a bunch of Gutenburg book and find every possible characters and bi-characters inside
Calculating their frequency in the text
For the cipher, do a look up and find the closest frequency

But after feeding 20+ books to my code, the result is still far from correct.
In the exemple, the bi-character 'es' got a frequency of 6% but in the fed text, the frequency if only around 2%
Did I missed something in the question or is it more on the method? Any idea? All kinds of help are appreciated.
Here's the code if needed:
from collections import Counter

import requests
import random as rnd
import re

##encryption part
def load_text_from_web(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for bad status codes
        return response.text
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while loading the text: {e}")
        return None
def cut_string_into_pairs(text):
  pairs = []
  for i in range(0, len(text) - 1, 2):
    pairs.append(text[i:i + 2])
  if len(text) % 2 != 0:
    pairs.append(text[-1] + '_')  # Add a placeholder if the string has an odd number of characters
  return pairs


def gen_key(symboles):

  l=len(symboles)
  if l > 256:
    return False

  rnd.seed(1337)
  int_keys = rnd.sample(list(range(l)),l)
  dictionary = dict({})
  for s,k in zip(symboles,int_keys):
    dictionary[s]="{:08b}".format(k )
  return dictionary

def M_vers_symboles(M, K):
    encoded_text = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(M):
        # Vérifie les paires de caractères
        if i + 1 < len(M):
            pair = M[i] + M[i + 1]
            if pair in K:
                encoded_text.append(pair)
                i += 2  # Sauter les deux caractères utilisés
                continue

        # Vérifie le caractère seul
        if M[i] in K:
            encoded_text.append(M[i])
        else:
            # Conserve le caractère tel quel si non trouvé
            encoded_text.append(M[i])
        i += 1

    return encoded_text

def chiffrer(M,K):
  l = M_vers_symboles(M, K)
  l = [K[x] for x in l]
  return ''.join(l)


def chiffrer2(M, K) -> str:
    encoded_text = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(M):
        # Vérifie les paires de caractères
        if i + 1 < len(M):
            pair = M[i] + M[i + 1]
            if pair in K:
                encoded_text.append(K[pair])
                i += 2  # Sauter les deux caractères utilisés
                continue

        # Vérifie le caractère seul
        if M[i] in K:
            encoded_text.append(K[M[i]])
        else:
            # Conserve le caractère tel quel si non trouvé
            encoded_text.append(M[i])
        i += 1

    return ''.join(encoded_text)


##decryption part
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/13846.txt.utf-8" 
text = load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/4650.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/69794.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/39331.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/67924.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/72071.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55639.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/66894.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/15212.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11046.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/67867.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55637.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/55766.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/66261.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()
url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/71208.txt.utf-8"
text = text + load_text_from_web(url).strip()


def character_frequency(input_text):
    character_frequencies = Counter(input_text)
    total_chars = sum(character_frequencies.values())
    frequency_dict = {char: (count / total_chars) for char, count in character_frequencies.items()}
    return frequency_dict


def bicharacter_frequency(input_text):
    bichars = [input_text[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(input_text) - 1)]
    bichar_frequencies = Counter(bichars)
    total_bichars = sum(bichar_frequencies.values())
    frequency_dict = {bichar: (count / total_bichars) for bichar, count in bichar_frequencies.items()}

    return frequency_dict

def divide_text(c, size=8):
    return [c[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(c), size)]

def find_key(text, d):
    tokens = divide_text(text, 8)
    freq_tokens_raw = Counter(tokens)
    total_tok = sum(freq_tokens_raw.values())
    freq_tokens = {token: (count / total_tok) for token, count in freq_tokens_raw.items()}
    print(freq_tokens)
    to_be_key = {}
    matched_key = []
    for k1, v1 in freq_tokens.items():
        candidates = [(k2, v2) for (k2, v2) in d.items()]
        candidates.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - v1))

        for k2, v2 in candidates:
            if k2 in matched_key:
                continue
            else:
                matched_key.append(k2)
                to_be_key[k1] = k2
                break

    return to_be_key

def decryp_text(c, d):
    m = ''
    for i in range(0, len(c), 8):
        token = c[i: i + 8]
        m = m + d.get(token)
    return m


dict_c = character_frequency(text)
dict_bc = bicharacter_frequency(text)
dict_all = {**dict_c, **dict_bc}

M1 = "es, les nations sur les nations, les vérités sur les erreurs, les erreurs sur les vérités. Tout se "

caracteres = list(set(list(M1)))
nb_caracteres = len(caracteres)
nb_bicaracteres = 256-nb_caracteres
bicaracteres = [item for item, _ in Counter(cut_string_into_pairs(M1)).most_common(nb_bicaracteres)]
symboles = caracteres + bicaracteres
nb_symboles = len(symboles)

K = gen_key(symboles)
C = chiffrer(M1, K)

if len(find_key(C, dict_all)) > 256:
    print('error')
else: 
    key = find_key(C, dict_all)
    print(key)
    print(decryp_text(C, key))
```


From the text it seems that you are expecting that the ciphertext contains the same characters & digrams as the plaintext. That's of course not how it works; you find the symbols or whatever that match the frequency of the characters / digrams of the plaintext and create a mapping. That mapping is probably not perfect though.
